# Delphi Firemonkey - Assigning Custom Alert to Notification Channel in Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to create a set of notification channels with custom alerts so end users can identify the type of alert from audio alone. The handsets we're targeting are all Android 8 or greater, and thus assigning

```
Notification.Soundname := <path here>
```

No longer functions, and the notification plays the default sound for the channel.

Furthermore, on channel creation, there is no sound property or variable to assign.

I've  been trawling through the JNI units supplied with Delphi 10.4.1 and in `Androidapi.JNI.App.pas`, lines 1797, 1805, 1816 there is this code:

```pascal
//function getAudioAttributes: JAudioAttributes; cdecl;
//function getSound: Jnet_Uri; cdecl;
//procedure setSound(sound: Jnet_Uri; audioAttributes: JAudioAttributes); cdecl;
```

Which sounds like exactly what I'm looking for, but uncommenting this code and adding `Androidapi.JNI.Media` into the `uses` clause for the unknown types ends in a circular reference.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate: [How to add and remove Android notification channels in Delphi Rio10.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670486/)

Comment: Regarding no sound property: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-23577

Comment: Also: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-23044, which has a workaround for the lack of a sound property. Be aware that it probably needs updating

Comment: RemyLebeau, this is not the issue, creating new channels is working just fine
DavidNottage, the first link describes the issue perfectly, the second link is only relevant to Android devices running < 8.0, where .Soundname would work so long as the file was in publicly accessible storage, the .Soundname property on the current TNotification object has no purpose or effect on Android 8+